# Is it safe to use a Mutex without Arc in multithreading?

Tags: multithreading, rust

```
lazy_static! {
    pub static ref A: Mutex<Vec<u8>> = Mutex::new(vec![]);
}

#[test]
fn test() {
    let mut handles = vec![];
    for _ in 0..100 {
        let handle = thread::spawn(|| for _ in 0..10000 { A.lock().unwrap().push(1); });
        handles.push(handle);
    }

    for handle in handles { handle.join().unwrap(); }
    println!("{}", A.lock().unwrap().len());
}
```

I got the output which was `1000000`, but I'm not sure this is a right way to collect the `data` in multithreading.

Should I change it to `Arc<Mutex<_>>`?

Comment: Rule of thumb for Rust: if you don't have to type `unsafe`, the code is memory safe, type safe and data-race free... aka "safe" ;)

Comment: I just have some confuse about `Arc`, and when to use it.

Comment: "When to use Arc?" is a different question though.

Comment: I figure it out now.    : )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is safe, yes. Multithreading is exactly what mutexes are for. `Arc` doesn't give you anything you need here.

Note, of course, that your current code is horrendously inefficient. I hope your real use case does a lot more work between mutex locks than this.

Comment: I have some threads which was in some threads. So I collect  the sub-sub-threads' `JoinHandle`. I need the main thread to wait for them. Any suggestion?

Comment: Why not have the creating thread wait for them before it exits? The main thread then waits for the creating thread, and it all works out.

Comment: But the creating thread have a lot of works to do, it's about flash sale. I don't want it to wait the payment thread.